# FOR output does not start with 0 element of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have problem with 0th array element as output of FOR cycles. I want server to print letters A B C D E; and if something is different as element in array, than it should be printed something else. So I made conditions and switch statement for that.

But 0th element of array is always printed out as different element. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Can you please help me? Can you explain me why is this happening?

```
<?php
    $array = array(0,1,2,3,4,"something");
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        echo '<br>'.$i;
        if ($array[$i] == 'something') {
            echo ' something ';
        } else {
            switch ($array[$i])
                {   case "0":
                        echo ' A';
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        echo ' B';
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        echo ' C';
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        echo ' D';
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        echo ' E';
                        break;
                    default:;
                };
            };
        };
    ?>
```

My output is this:

```
0 something 
1 B
2 C
3 D
4 E
5 something
```

But I am expecting this:

```
0 A 
1 B
2 C
3 D
4 E
5 something
```

Comment: try adding `reset($array)` before your loop

Comment: Most strings are equal to `0` in PHP, use `===` to stop this. You can test this yourself with `var_dump(0 == "hello");`

Comment: Did you try `0 == 'something'` first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When comparing integer `0` to string `"something"` the string is cast as integer. See:

```
var_dump((int) 0); // yields int 0
var_dump((int) 'something'); // yields int 0
```

See [PHP bug request 39579](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39579). Note, this is NOT a bug, and works as "expected."

The proper comparison should use strict equality (3 equal signs which test both the *value* and the *type*):

```
if ($array[$i] === 'something') {
    echo ' something ';
}
```

Alternatively, you may cast the "known/assumed" type during the comparison *temporarily* and still maintain loose equality:

```
if ((string) $array[$i] == 'something') {
    echo ' something ';
}

// OR with strval

if (strval($array[$i]) == 'something') {
    echo ' something ';
}
```

Comment: Thank you deeper explanation. I will check it out. === works perfectly

Comment: accepted but cannot upvote, sorry I do not have reputation for this action.